# VB.NET: application.restart() enters break mode

Tags: vb.net

Exactly what the title says. When I'm debugging my project and I enter the part where the application restarts (using `Application.Restart()`) Visual Studio opens break mode. Is there any way to prevent this from happening and restart the application?

It also sometimes comes up with `System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: 'The operation was canceled by the user'`, is there a better way to restart the application? I can't simply reset the variables as I disposed a few of them.

Comment: `Restart` creates a new process, the debugger is not attached to it. I haven't tested it, but maybe you can use this tool: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2014/11/24/introducing-the-child-process-debugging-power-tool/

Comment: Using it as a separate application just closes it altogether, so I'm not sure if the debugger has anything to do with it.